# How to remove strings from a list in Python in a loop so it won't be used as a duplicate?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted this part of the code to print false when using a word such as "soon" since there is an extra o missing from the list. I'm not exactly sure how remove a string so that it won't be used twice.

```
def word_from_lst(lst, word):    
    """returns True if word can be obtained from a list of strings"""   
    if word == " ":                            
        return True                            
    if word[0] in lst: 
        return word_from_lst(lst, word[1:])
    return False                            

print (word_from_lst(["a", "s", "n", "f", "o"], "soon"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recusive Solution**

Your solution is recursive, so let's start with that

```
def word_from_lst(lst, word):
    if word == " " or not word:                             
      return True                            
    if word[0] in lst: 
      lst_ = lst[:]
      lst_.remove(word[0])
      return word_from_lst(lst_, word[1:])
    return False
```

What's happening here is that I am reducing `lst` in addition to reducing `word`. I'm making a copy of `lst` so we don't modify the original. It might not seem like a big deal here, but it can cause some pain if you find out this function was used somewhere and deleted your list. This does use a little more space if that's a concern.

**Iterative Solution**

We can make it iterative if you have a large input:

```
def word_from_lst(lst, word):
    lst_ = lst[:]
    for c in word:                
        if c in lst_: 
          lst_.remove(c)
        else:
          return False
    return True
```

The iterative solution is linear in the size of word and doesn't modify the original list, so it's probably the best solution.

```
In [36]: %timeit word_from_lst(list('noooos'), 'soon')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 µs per loop
```

**"Interesting" solutions**

But there are some interesting ways we could use the standard library to solve the problem.

One way to say this is that word must be a permutation of a subset of lst.

```
import itertools
def word_from_list(lst, word):
    size = len(word)
    tuple(word) in itertools.permutations(lst, size)

In [39]: %timeit word_from_list(list('noooos'), 'soon')
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.1 µs per loop
```

Another way to pose the problem is that all of the characters from word have to be in lst and word must contain no more of each character.

```
from collections import Counter
def word_from_list2(lst, word):
    word_ct = Counter(word)
    lst_ct = Counter(lst)
    return all([word_ct[w] <= lst_ct[w] for w in word_ct])

In [46]: %timeit word_from_list(list('noooos'), 'soon')
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.2 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
def word_from_lst(lst, word):

    """returns True if word can be obtained from a list of strings"""

    if word == " ":                            
        return True

    for letter in word:
        if letter in lst:
            lst.remove(letter)
        else:
            return False                            

    return True                            

print (word_from_lst(["a", "s", "n", "f", "o"], "soon"))
```

Comment: This is a better way of doing it as it does not suffer from the flaw that @jeremycg's solution does. If you provide more of one letter than exist in the target string, it will still return true.

Comment: This is destructive to the input list, which might not be desirable

Comment: @munk a copy of the list could be made inside the function

Comment: @danidee That's true. The scenario I'm imagining is: an intern or junior dev being in a hurry, copy/pasting this as a solution somewhere deep in a code base I'll have to work on and then me wondering later on why my list is now ["a","f"] and losing 30 minutes of my life to debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use python built in set collection (unless you need to keep the original order...)?

```
clean_list = list(set(your_list))
```

Comment: I think the question asks for something different. The number of same letters in the list is important.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit 2:
I misread the question. I will be more careful in the future.** I've kept the others of for reference in case they are needed. At any rate, this one should do what OP wants:

```
def canBeMade(listOfLetters, stringToMake):
    lDict = dict((letter, listOfLetters.count(letter)) for letter in set(listOfLetters))
    for l in stringToMake:
        if l not in lDict: return False
        if stringToMake.count(l) > lDict[l]: return False
    return True

print canBeMade('noooos', 'soon')
```

**Original**
You're looking for the Cartesian Product of the string.

```
from itertools import product

def canBeMade(listOfLetters, stringToMake):
    # make it a bit more efficient by pruning out all letters that are not in the string
    listOfLetters = set(filter(lambda x: x in stringToMake, listOfLetters))
    for element in product(listOfLetters, repeat=len(stringToMake)):
        if ''.join(element) == stringToMake:
            return True
    return False

print canBeMade(['s', 'o', 'n', 's', 'a', 't'], "soon")
```

**Edit:** Even easier, and without all the nonsense:

```
def canBeMade(listOfLetters, stringToMake):
    for l in stringToMake:
        if l not in listOfLetters:
            return False
    return True
assert canBeMade(['s', 'o', 's', 'a', 't'], "soon") == False
assert canBeMade('nos', "soon") == True
```

Comment: Oh, my appologies. Your answer is better.

Answer (score -1):

**[solution 1]** One possible way is to use dictionaries:

```
def word_from_lst(lst, word):
    char_count = {l:word.count(l) for l in word}

    for key, value in char_count.iteritems():
        if lst.count(key) < value:
             return False
    return True

print word_from_lst(["a", "s", "n", "f", "o"], "soon")
False

print word_from_lst(["a", "s", "n", "f", "o", "o"], "soon")
True
```

This way, you are not changing your original list and word.

**[solution 2]**  Alternatively, you can remove each character from your list that exists in the word in each iteration. In that case, if in the next iteration the same character from the word doesn't exist in the new list, it will return False:

```
def word_from_lst(lst, word):    
    for l in word:                         
        if l not in lst:
            return False
        else:
            lst.remove(l) 

    return True
```

Of course, none of these are recursive if that's what you are looking for.

**[solution 3]** To make your original recursive function work, you can remove the character you just checked from the list, and pass the new list (the logic is similar to solution 2:

```
def word_from_lst(lst, word):    
    if word == " ":                            
        return True

    if word[0] in lst:
        tmp_list = list(lst)
        tmp_list.remove(word[0])
        return word_from_lst(tmp_list, word[1:])

    return False
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, all three solutions in my answer are valid. Not sure why this got a "not useful" vote without any comments. Same goes for the answer that @Goodies gave.